# Maximum number of fields support to be included in _source.includes in Elastic search for _search api?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

While querying an index with more than 1500 fields included inside _source.includes, I'm getting following error from ES.

**Error Log:**

```
{
  "took": 154,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 28,
    "successful": 15,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 13,
    "failures": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "index123",
        "node": "...",
        "reason": {
          "type": "too_complex_to_determinize_exception",
          "reason": "too_complex_to_determinize_exception: Determinizing automaton with 52903 states and 54499 transitions would result in more than 10000 states."
        }
      }
    ]
  },....
```

Here is the sample query I'm trying to execute.

**Query Sample:**

```
{
    "explain": false,
    "size": 20,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "terms": {
                                    "boost": 1,
                                    "type": [
                                        "University"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "_source": {
        "excludes": [
            
        ],
        "includes": [
            --1579 fields included --
        ]
    }
    
}
```

**Note**: When tried lowering number of fields to around 1440 inside *_source.includes*, ES was able to give response with no error.

I was wondering if there is any hard limit on number fields that can be added inside _source or any config settings to increase that limit.

It would also be helpful, if there's any alternative to get such high number fields to be included and returned from ES.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many fields do you have in your index mapping? What happens if you use `fields: [...]` instead of `_source: [...]`?

Comment: If you're getting (almost?) all fields anyway, it might be actually more performant to return the whole `_source` (remove `_source` from query altogether)?

Comment: @Val, I have more than 1600 fields in multiple types. Use of fields:[..] instead of _source gave the result but could you explain why ES behave differently between fields:[] &n _source. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @ilvar, Yaa removing the _source at all would give me the result but my use case was to pull not all fields. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: This is the reason why `fields` works when `_source` fails: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/49028

Answer (score 0):

With so many fields, you should either exclude (using `_source.excludes`) the ones you don't need instead of including the ones you need, there would be less fields in your query.

Another solution, because [`_source` has limitations with a high number of fields](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/49028), you can also leverage the [`fields` option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-fields.html#search-fields-param) which usually performs better than `_source`.